# Symfony Templates within Templates

Tags: php, symfony1

Sorry if this seems incredibly simple. I am only new to Symfony.

I just want to have a template/view which "contains" other views. So, for the following example, imagine on my /dashboard/ it will show both "statistics" and "inbox". I want the code for each of these to be within separate actions/methods.

```
<?php

class dashboardActions extends sfActions
{
    public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {
        // Load statisticsSuccess
        // Load inboxSuccess

        // Render them both "within" index template
    }

    public function executeStatistics(sfWebRequest $request) {
        // Render statisticsSuccess
    }

    public function executeInbox(sfWebRequest $request) {
        // Render inboxSuccess
    }
}
```

Thanks for any assistance you can provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make "statistics" and "inbox" [components](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_components). Be sure to reference the documentation of the version of Symfony you're using.

Comment: thanks mate, exactly what I was looking for. Will accept your answer once it lets me.